# «Заподозрить в подвохе» — правильно? Значение слова «глуздырь»

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, управление

[А. Князева. Девушка из тихого омута](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=78624&p=37) (Новгородское княжество, XIII век):

> — Подъехала на коне, вытерла об порты свой кровавый меч, окинула оком бранное поле… С тех самых пор ей и служу.
>   — Да правда ли это? – Савоська **заподозрил деда в подвохе**.
>   — Правду говорю. Кабы не она, лежал бы в сырой земле. — Перекрестившись, Кондрат набросил на паренька лошадиную попону: — Спи, **глуздырь**, не попурхивай!
>   Через минуту мальчишка уже сопел и чмокал во сне.

1. Подскажите, правильно ли говорить **заподозрить [кого-то] в подвохе**?
2. Каково значение слова **глуздырь** в этом контексте?
   (У Фасмера: птенец, еще не умеющий летать.)

Comment: "Заподозрить в подвохе" - по-моему, нормально. Чем оно вам не глянулось? "Глуздырь" в первый раз вижу, я бы ещё спросил про "попурхивать". А вообще чем-то напоминает бессмертный отрывок про старика Ромуальдыча, это где "рассупонилось солнышко, расталдыкнуло свои лучи по белу светушку". Стиль писателей-почвенников живёт, цветёт, и пахнет.

Comment: Мне кажется, что говорят **заподозрить подвох** — без предлога. https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%85

Comment: @freim В словаре: _попурхивать — вспархивать._ http://feb-web.ru/feb/byliny/texts/bpu/bpu-537-.htm?cmd=p

Comment: Мне кажется, что можно сказать и так, и так - в зависимости от контекста. "Заподозрить что-то" и заподозрить в чём-то" - это немного разные по смыслу выражения, но оба употребимы. В данном случае - "деда в подвохе".

Answer (score 1):

ГЛУЗД — муж. или глузды мн., южн., зап. ум, память, рассудок, толк; | мозг. Сбился с глузду, с толку; спился с глузду, с ума. Отбить глузды, бить по голове. На всю Польшу один комар глузду принес. Глуздырь муж. глуздырко жен. умник, разумник; внасмех, дурень Толковый словарь Даля

В данном предложении «умник» употребляется с иронией.
«Заподозрить кого-то в чем-то», включая в подвохе — нормальное сочетание.

Answer (score 1):

Подвох - шутка со скрытой целью **обмануть** кого-либо, поставить в трудное, неприятное положение.

То есть в данном случае это сопоставимо с "заподозрить в обмане". Возможно, что выражение "заподозрить в подвохе" нестандартное, но оно допустимо.

Глуздырь - глупый маленький ребёнок. Это старинное слово, ещё со времён Даля.

Comment: Пропустила ответы на собственный вопрос — извиняюсь-поправляюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Все проще. Зависит от залога. Заподозрил подвох   / НО: был заподозрен в подвохе. Вот и вся наука